I can't change the city dots on my map to graduated color
I have a map with Census places (cities) and have added in a score that I want to map. I am looking for graduated colored dots. Changing size of dots seems to work, but graduated colors don't -- the dots stay yellow. enter image description here
What am I doing wrong?



Make sure your points arent selected, the selection color is yellow: https://imgur.com/a/ZJdl5Mc

That's embarrassing. The selection was on. Thank you for helping!!

Feel free to add that as an answer below and mark this question as "answered", then it might help the next person...
